# how to replace letters in 1 word

Tags: java, android

how replace the letters **a, i, u, e** in all words to be **o**?

example words :

i like it's, i want finish

becomes

o loko ot's, o wont fonosh

my code :

```
private EditText editText;
private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private String funny_views;
private static final String REMOVE_ALPHABET = "a,i,u,e";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.funny_textView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.funny_button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.funny_textView2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int viewId = v.getId();
            if (viewId == R.id.funny_button) {
            funny_views = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            String funny_name = funny_views + REMOVE_ALPHABET;
            textView.setText(funny_name);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe someone here can help my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
String funny_name = funny_views.replaceAll("[aiue]", "o");
```